# Meteor build not working

Tags: meteor, amazon-ec2, rocket.chat

"meteor build" not working for me

http://screencast.com/t/iOjtsnA2l

I am on ubuntu 14 - Amazon Web Services (AWS)

And

I used these steps
https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/pre-requisites/

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have found the issue, you need to specify an output directory. e.g. `meteor build ../release` would put the created tarball in the specified directory.

Comment: Thanks :) Yes i'm in the Rocket.Chat directory

Comment: @MedBou I updated the answer, you need to specify an output directory for the generated tarball to be placed in.

Comment: I think that is the issue, you can see the example build script here: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/blob/develop/example-build.sh